# Check existing value on different table in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, logic

I have two tables that are already linked, and I'm attempting to verify if an AccountNumber from one table exists in the other. My attempt to create a new column using the provided code snippet didn't yield the expected results.

```
IF(FILTER(Close,Close[AccountNumber]) = FILTER(Price,Price[AccountNumber]), 1, 0)
```

Could someone kindly review this code and suggest any necessary modifications or alternative approaches to achieve this comparison effectively? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should start here:  [Learn DAX basics in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-quickstart-learn-dax-basics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already figure it out, tried the solution below and it works!

```
IF (Close[AccountNumber] IN DISTINCT (Price[AccountNumber]), 1, 0)
```